# Need help with collection joinField() - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, collection, sql, join

Can anyone describe how to use `joinField()` method of collection (`Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection`).

I actually don't know what means each argument:

```
public function joinField($alias, $table, $field, $bind, $cond = null, $joinType = 'inner')
...
```

Great Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function describes itself if you check comments added before the function.

```
/**
 * Join regular table field and use an attribute as fk
 *
 * Examples:
 * ('country_name', 'directory_country_name', 'name', 'country_id=shipping_country',
 *      "{{table}}.language_code='en'", 'left')
 *
 * @param string $alias 'country_name'
 * @param string $table 'directory_country_name'
 * @param string $field 'name'
 * @param string $bind 'PK(country_id)=FK(shipping_country_id)'
 * @param string|array $cond "{{table}}.language_code='en'" OR array('language_code'=>'en')
 * @param string $joinType 'left'
 * @return $this
 * @throws LocalizedException
 */
```

First Argument is `$alias` which allows to add the alias for the table name we want to join.
Second argument is `$table` which is actual table name in the database.
Third argument is `$field`, the field which we want to join
Fourth argument is `$bind` where you define the `ON` condition of your sql query
Fifth argument is `$cond` which allows to add `where` conditions
Last argument is `$joinType` which defines your table join type. `left`, `right`, `inner`

Comment: I've updated question

Comment: @KyryloRomantsov, please check updated answer

Comment: That error still occure

Comment: @KyryloRomantsov, I had checked the table and had updated the column names as required. please check now

Comment: it doesn't work, I can't understand how to make fk

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: @KyryloRomantsov, please check edit section code.

Comment: Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid attribute name: sales_report.product_id - i am going to cry now

Comment: may be I should create foreign key?

Comment: Or I should replace 'main_table' with some value

Comment: @KyryloRomantsov, No, you do not require to create foreign key. and `main_table` is MySQL alias for the table on which you are using join query so you dont need to update it too.

Comment: but it doesn't work

Comment: Same thing happened to me regarding an issue with product_id - as I was referencing the product_entitiy table, you had to use "entity_id": e.g. `$collection->joinField('cids', 'catalog_category_product', 'product_id', 'product_id = entity_id', '{{table}}.category_id = 7', 'left')` compiles into `LEFT JOIN catalog_category_product AS at_cids ON (at_cids.product_id=e.entity_id) AND (at_cids.category_id = 7)`. Bear in mind that the foreign key is the former main table. If all else fails, use `$collection->getSelect()->join()`.